# Separating a string by any white space in C

Tags: c, string, token, whitespace, tokenize

I have a string such as "123 789" and my desired result is to separate the string for this output:

```
123 
789
```

I have created code that accomplishes this, separating the string by finding a space.

I need help editing my code to also separate the string by carriage return, new-line, vertical tab, free-formed tab, or a sequence of blanks. Basically, any white space character. Currently, if anything other than a single space separates the different parts of the string, my code breaks.

Here is my code that currently separates by a single space:

```
int counter = 0; //counter used in loop
int index = test->current_index; //holds the current index of my string, it's initially 0
char *string = test->myString; //holds the whole string

char token_buffer = string[index];

//before loop: index = 0, counter = 0

while(test->current_index <= test->end_index)
{
    counter = 0;
    token_buffer = string[counter+index];
    while(token_buffer != ' ' && (index+counter)<=test->end_index)
    {
        counter++;
        token_buffer = string[index+counter];
    }

    char *output_token = malloc(counter+1);
    strncpy(output_token,string+index,counter);
    printf("%s \n", output_token);
    TestProcessing(output_token); //sends each token to be processed further

    //update information
    counter++;   
    test->current_index += counter;
    index += counter;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `strtok()` ?

Comment: @Bret A note to consider please. You posted some questions in the past days making the community teach you programming. That is not fair. You also never accepted any answer given to you by any SO user. I reckon you don't even vote up/down, as the view votes I see were partly from me. Please read about SO and try to participate.

Comment: Tip: don't use tabs in the material pasted into a SO question or answer; it make it hard to manage the alignment sensibly. The `return 0;` at the end of the loop body is unexpected; are you sure you have all the code in the question?  (Answer: you don't have all the code — the function definition isn't visible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a util function like this,

```
int is_delimiter(char c)
{
    char delimiters[] = {'\0','\n','\r',' '};//customize to expand  
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(delimiters); i++){
         if(delimiters[i] == c)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then,

```
while(!is_delimiter(token_buffer) && (index+counter)<=test->end_index)
```

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Thanks. Take a time to learn and be back :)  Does that mean just need `sizeof(delimiters)` here in C99?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this code could be most easily modified to accommodate for your requirements by including `<ctype.h>` and replacing `token_buffer != ' '` with `!isspace(token_buffer)`.

Alternatively, you could replace that entire loop with a call to `strcspn` (from `<string.h>`).

Comment: I agree. To use library is more safe and robust if it meets requirement.

Answer (score 0):

About the bare simplest way to separate the string is with `strtok` or `strsep` (both in `string.h`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char string[] ="123 789";
    char *p = NULL;

    for (p = strtok (string, " "); p; p = strtok (NULL, " \n"))
        printf (" %s\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_min
 123
 789
```

**Note:** the original string is not preserved, so make a copy if you need to original later.